# How do I create an index online with liquibase?

Tags: oracle, migration, liquibase

I have a migration that will create an index in a table of our Oracle database.  The DBA would like the index to be created ONLINE.  (Something like `CREATE INDEX ..... ONLINE;`)  Is there something I can add to the tag below to accomplish what I want or do I need to write the SQL into the migration?

```
<createIndex tableName="USER" indexName="IX_USER_TX_ID">
     <column name="TX_ID" />
</createIndex>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard  tag to specify it as ONLINE. Your 3 options to create it as ONLINE are:

1. Fall back to the  tag where you specify the exact SQL you want
2. Use the [modifySql tag](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html) to append to the generated SQL.
3. Create an [extension](http://liquibase.org/extensions) to createIndex that always generates ONLINE at the end of the SQL or adds a parameter to createIndex that allows you to control if it is added or not.

Option #2 is probably the best mix of easy yet flexible and would look something like this:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="nvoxland">
    <createIndex tableName="USER" indexName="IX_USER_TX_ID">
        <column name="TX_ID" />
    </createIndex>
    <modifySql dbms="oracle">
         <append value=" ONLINE"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

Notice the space in the value tag. Append does a very simple text append with no built-in logic.